# Why knit2html() function cannot resolve TOC(table of content)?

Tags: r, knitr

When I directly click "knit html" in RStudio, it would correctly print my toc.

But I want to output a .md file.

knit2html() seems cannot output a toc in both .md and .html.

Can someone explain the reason ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following header:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "DM"
date: "Saturday, September 06, 2014"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    keep_md: true

---
```

You should have a more recent version of knitr installed from github to make keep_md work. keep_md does not delete the md file after processing. However, the md-file does not contain a toc, because it is only generated in the html-step.

Comment: Thank you DM.1. After I added this options, the output file still cannot show toc.    2. What does `keep_md` mean for?

Comment: See answer. You cannot see the toc in the md.

Comment: Thank you DM. That makes sense. However, after using knit2hitml() function, its outputed .html file does not contain toc as well.

Comment: Try the button in RStudio. If it does not work, post your sessionInfo(). Make sure that you have items with # and ## separated by emptying lines.

Comment: Good to know it works; following SO habit, you should check the answer as accepted.